# can not load native library

Tags: android, java-native-interface, unsatisfiedlinkerror

I am developing a epub reader application, when I am loading it it shows a error that the reader cannot load native library, below I am attaching the log cat of the file.

```
11-05 15:41:01.980: I/Process(445): Sending signal. PID: 445 SIG: 9
11-05 15:41:02.090: I/ActivityManager(70): Process org.geometerplus.zlibrary.ui.android (pid 445) has died.
11-05 15:41:02.115: E/InputDispatcher(70): channel '406f9968 org.geometerplus.zlibrary.ui.android/org.geometerplus.android.fbreader.FBReader (server)' ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x8
11-05 15:41:02.115: E/InputDispatcher(70): channel '406f9968 org.geometerplus.zlibrary.ui.android/org.geometerplus.android.fbreader.FBReader (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
11-05 15:41:02.175: I/WindowManager(70): WIN DEATH: Window{406f9968 org.geometerplus.zlibrary.ui.android/org.geometerplus.android.fbreader.FBReader paused=true}
11-05 15:41:02.235: I/WindowManager(70): WIN DEATH: Window{406ffa08 org.geometerplus.zlibrary.ui.android/org.geometerplus.android.fbreader.FBReader paused=true}
11-05 15:41:02.425: I/WindowManager(70): WIN DEATH: Window{40705430 org.geometerplus.zlibrary.ui.android/org.geometerplus.android.fbreader.FBReader paused=true}
11-05 15:41:02.565: E/InputDispatcher(70): Received spurious receive callback for unknown input channel.  fd=181, events=0x8
11-05 15:41:02.565: E/InputDispatcher(70): Received spurious receive callback for unknown input channel.  fd=185, events=0x8
11-05 15:41:02.785: I/ActivityManager(70): Start proc org.geometerplus.zlibrary.ui.android:crash for activity org.geometerplus.zlibrary.ui.android/org.geometerplus.android.fbreader.crash.MissingNativeLibraryActivity: pid=468 uid=10044 gids={3003, 1015}
11-05 15:41:06.005: I/ActivityManager(70): Displayed org.geometerplus.zlibrary.ui.android/org.geometerplus.android.fbreader.crash.MissingNativeLibraryActivity: +3s304ms (total +18s82ms)
11-05 15:41:13.185: D/dalvikvm(328): GC_EXPLICIT freed 321K, 54% free 2540K/5511K, external 1625K/2137K, paused 107ms
11-05 15:41:15.705: D/SntpClient(70): request time failed: java.net.SocketException: Address family not supported by protocol
11-05 15:41:21.855: D/dalvikvm(285): GC_EXPLICIT freed 9K, 55% free 2595K/5767K, external 1625K/2137K, paused 74ms
11-05 15:45:38.435: I/ActivityManager(70): Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=org.geometerplus.zlibrary.ui.android/org.geometerplus.android.fbreader.FBReader } from pid 145
11-05 15:45:38.855: I/ActivityManager(70): Start proc org.geometerplus.zlibrary.ui.android for activity org.geometerplus.zlibrary.ui.android/org.geometerplus.android.fbreader.FBReader: pid=477 uid=10044 gids={3003, 1015}
11-05 15:45:44.916: D/dalvikvm(70): GREF has increased to 401
11-05 15:45:45.376: D/dalvikvm(477): GC_EXPLICIT freed 435K, 51% free 3062K/6151K, external 1625K/2137K, paused 117ms
11-05 15:45:45.555: D/dalvikvm(477): GC_EXPLICIT freed 5K, 51% free 3057K/6151K, external 1625K/2137K, paused 109ms
11-05 15:45:45.685: D/dalvikvm(477): GC_EXPLICIT freed 13K, 51% free 3048K/6151K, external 1625K/2137K, paused 83ms
11-05 15:45:45.836: D/dalvikvm(477): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 1K, 51% free 3057K/6151K, external 1625K/2137K, paused 114ms
11-05 15:45:46.345: I/ActivityManager(70): Displayed org.geometerplus.zlibrary.ui.android/org.geometerplus.android.fbreader.FBReader: +7s531ms
11-05 15:45:48.975: W/dalvikvm(477): Exception Ljava/lang/UnsatisfiedLinkError; thrown while initializing Lorg/geometerplus/fbreader/formats/PluginCollection;
11-05 15:45:48.985: W/dalvikvm(477): threadid=9: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
11-05 15:45:49.046: W/System.err(477): java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
11-05 15:45:49.067: W/System.err(477):  at org.geometerplus.fbreader.library.Book.getPlugin(Book.java:159)
11-05 15:45:49.067: W/System.err(477):  at org.geometerplus.fbreader.library.Book.<init>(Book.java:135)
11-05 15:45:49.075: W/System.err(477):  at org.geometerplus.fbreader.library.Book.getByFile(Book.java:96)
11-05 15:45:49.086: W/System.err(477):  at org.geometerplus.fbreader.fbreader.FBReaderApp.openBookInternal(FBReaderApp.java:233)
11-05 15:45:49.115: W/System.err(477):  at org.geometerplus.fbreader.fbreader.FBReaderApp$1.run(FBReaderApp.java:157)
11-05 15:45:49.115: W/System.err(477):  at org.geometerplus.android.util.UIUtil$3$1.run(UIUtil.java:120)
11-05 15:45:49.125: W/System.err(477): Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load NativeFormats-v2: findLibrary returned null
11-05 15:45:49.125: W/System.err(477):  at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:429)
11-05 15:45:49.146: W/System.err(477):  at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:554)
11-05 15:45:49.146: W/System.err(477):  at org.geometerplus.fbreader.formats.PluginCollection.<clinit>(PluginCollection.java:33)
11-05 15:45:49.166: W/System.err(477):  ... 6 more
11-05 15:45:49.177: I/ActivityManager(70): Starting: Intent { act=android.fbreader.action.CRASH dat=ExceptionInInitializerError: cmp=org.geometerplus.zlibrary.ui.android/org.geometerplus.android.fbreader.crash.MissingNativeLibraryActivity } from pid 477
11-05 15:45:49.325: I/Process(477): Sending signal. PID: 477 SIG: 9
11-05 15:45:49.578: I/ActivityManager(70): Process org.geometerplus.zlibrary.ui.android (pid 477) has died.
11-05 15:45:49.586: E/InputDispatcher(70): channel '407cc278 org.geometerplus.zlibrary.ui.android/org.geometerplus.android.fbreader.FBReader (server)' ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x8
11-05 15:45:49.586: E/InputDispatcher(70): channel '407cc278 org.geometerplus.zlibrary.ui.android/org.geometerplus.android.fbreader.FBReader (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
11-05 15:45:49.805: W/ActivityManager(70): Activity pause timeout for HistoryRecord{406e37c0 org.geometerplus.zlibrary.ui.android/org.geometerplus.android.fbreader.FBReader}
11-05 15:45:49.975: I/WindowManager(70): WIN DEATH: Window{407cc278 org.geometerplus.zlibrary.ui.android/org.geometerplus.android.fbreader.FBReader paused=true}
11-05 15:45:50.146: I/WindowManager(70): WIN DEATH: Window{407e92f0 org.geometerplus.zlibrary.ui.android/org.geometerplus.android.fbreader.FBReader paused=true}
11-05 15:45:50.265: E/InputDispatcher(70): Received spurious receive callback for unknown input channel.  fd=152, events=0x8
11-05 15:45:50.746: D/dalvikvm(468): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 312K, 50% free 2954K/5895K, external 2032K/2137K, paused 229ms
11-05 15:45:51.055: W/InputManagerService(70): Got RemoteException sending setActive(false) notification to pid 477 uid 10044
11-05 15:45:53.208: I/ActivityManager(70): Displayed org.geometerplus.zlibrary.ui.android/org.geometerplus.android.fbreader.crash.MissingNativeLibraryActivity: +2s884ms
11-05 15:45:57.405: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(145): showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
11-05 15:46:05.297: D/dalvikvm(456): GC_EXPLICIT freed 76K, 52% free 2633K/5379K, external 1625K/2137K, paused 143ms
11-05 15:46:10.276: D/dalvikvm(468): GC_EXPLICIT freed 13K, 50% free 2964K/5895K, external 2379K/2971K, paused 111ms
11-05 15:46:15.775: D/SntpClient(70): request time failed: java.net.SocketException: Address family not supported by protocol
11-05 15:50:04.305: I/ActivityManager(70): Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=org.geometerplus.zlibrary.ui.android/org.geometerplus.android.fbreader.FBReader } from pid 145
11-05 15:50:04.495: I/ActivityManager(70): Start proc org.geometerplus.zlibrary.ui.android for activity org.geometerplus.zlibrary.ui.android/org.geometerplus.android.fbreader.FBReader: pid=491 uid=10044 gids={3003, 1015}
11-05 15:50:09.456: D/dalvikvm(491): GC_EXPLICIT freed 454K, 51% free 3062K/6151K, external 1625K/2137K, paused 139ms
11-05 15:50:09.765: D/dalvikvm(491): GC_EXPLICIT freed 7K, 51% free 3057K/6151K, external 1625K/2137K, paused 148ms
11-05 15:50:09.945: D/dalvikvm(491): GC_EXPLICIT freed 1K, 51% free 3057K/6151K, external 1625K/2137K, paused 146ms
11-05 15:50:10.435: D/dalvikvm(491): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 11K, 51% free 3057K/6151K, external 1625K/2137K, paused 424ms
11-05 15:50:11.325: I/ActivityManager(70): Displayed org.geometerplus.zlibrary.ui.android/org.geometerplus.android.fbreader.FBReader: +6s905ms
11-05 15:50:13.985: W/dalvikvm(491): Exception Ljava/lang/UnsatisfiedLinkError; thrown while initializing Lorg/geometerplus/fbreader/formats/PluginCollection;
11-05 15:50:13.997: W/dalvikvm(491): threadid=9: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
11-05 15:50:14.166: W/System.err(491): java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
11-05 15:50:14.166: W/System.err(491):  at org.geometerplus.fbreader.library.Book.getPlugin(Book.java:159)
11-05 15:50:14.166: W/System.err(491):  at org.geometerplus.fbreader.library.Book.<init>(Book.java:135)
11-05 15:50:14.166: W/System.err(491):  at org.geometerplus.fbreader.library.Book.getByFile(Book.java:96)
11-05 15:50:14.175: W/System.err(491):  at org.geometerplus.fbreader.fbreader.FBReaderApp.openBookInternal(FBReaderApp.java:233)
11-05 15:50:14.175: W/System.err(491):  at org.geometerplus.fbreader.fbreader.FBReaderApp$1.run(FBReaderApp.java:157)
11-05 15:50:14.185: W/System.err(491):  at org.geometerplus.android.util.UIUtil$3$1.run(UIUtil.java:120)
11-05 15:50:14.185: W/System.err(491): Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load NativeFormats-v2: findLibrary returned null
11-05 15:50:14.185: W/System.err(491):  at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:429)
11-05 15:50:14.235: W/System.err(491):  at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:554)
11-05 15:50:14.235: W/System.err(491):  at org.geometerplus.fbreader.formats.PluginCollection.<clinit>(PluginCollection.java:33)
11-05 15:50:14.235: W/System.err(491):  ... 6 more
11-05 15:50:14.365: I/ActivityManager(70): Starting: Intent { act=android.fbreader.action.CRASH dat=ExceptionInInitializerError: cmp=org.geometerplus.zlibrary.ui.android/org.geometerplus.android.fbreader.crash.MissingNativeLibraryActivity } from pid 491
11-05 15:50:14.456: I/Process(491): Sending signal. PID: 491 SIG: 9
11-05 15:50:14.621: I/ActivityManager(70): Process org.geometerplus.zlibrary.ui.android (pid 491) has died.
11-05 15:50:14.665: E/InputDispatcher(70): channel '4076a8e0 org.geometerplus.zlibrary.ui.android/org.geometerplus.android.fbreader.FBReader (server)' ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x8
11-05 15:50:14.665: E/InputDispatcher(70): channel '4076a8e0 org.geometerplus.zlibrary.ui.android/org.geometerplus.android.fbreader.FBReader (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
11-05 15:50:14.786: I/WindowManager(70): WIN DEATH: Window{4076a8e0 org.geometerplus.zlibrary.ui.android/org.geometerplus.android.fbreader.FBReader paused=true}
11-05 15:50:14.936: W/ActivityManager(70): Activity pause timeout for HistoryRecord{40613df0 org.geometerplus.zlibrary.ui.android/org.geometerplus.android.fbreader.FBReader}
11-05 15:50:15.376: I/WindowManager(70): WIN DEATH: Window{40611fa0 org.geometerplus.zlibrary.ui.android/org.geometerplus.android.fbreader.FBReader paused=true}
11-05 15:50:15.697: E/InputDispatcher(70): Received spurious receive callback for unknown input channel.  fd=152, events=0x8
11-05 15:50:16.796: W/InputManagerService(70): Got RemoteException sending setActive(false) notification to pid 491 uid 10044
11-05 15:50:19.055: I/ActivityManager(70): Displayed org.geometerplus.zlibrary.ui.android/org.geometerplus.android.fbreader.crash.MissingNativeLibraryActivity: +3s151ms
11-05 15:50:24.215: D/dalvikvm(145): GC_EXPLICIT freed 170K, 50% free 3020K/6023K, external 6250K/7660K, paused 141ms
11-05 15:50:29.247: D/dalvikvm(456): GC_EXPLICIT freed 3K, 52% free 2632K/5379K, external 1625K/2137K, paused 130ms
11-05 15:51:15.785: D/SntpClient(70): request time failed: java.net.SocketException: Address family not supported by protocol
11-05 15:56:15.819: D/SntpClient(70): request time failed: java.net.SocketException: Address family not supported by protocol
11-05 16:01:15.875: D/SntpClient(70): request time failed: java.net.SocketException: Address family not supported by protocol
11-05 16:06:17.818: D/SntpClient(70): request time failed: java.net.SocketException: Address family not supported by protocol
11-05 16:11:17.846: D/SntpClient(70): request time failed: java.net.SocketException: Address family not supported by protocol
11-05 16:16:17.860: D/SntpClient(70): request time failed: java.net.SocketException: Address family not supported by protocol
11-05 16:21:17.887: D/SntpClient(70): request time failed: java.net.SocketException: Address family not supported by protocol
11-05 16:26:17.895: D/SntpClient(70): request time failed: java.net.SocketException: Address family not supported by protocol
11-05 16:30:38.037: D/PerformBackupThread(70): starting agent for backup of BackupRequest{app=ApplicationInfo{405c2c30 com.android.providers.settings} full=false}
11-05 16:30:38.138: D/BackupManagerService(70): awaiting agent for ApplicationInfo{405c2c30 com.android.providers.settings}
11-05 16:30:38.145: D/BackupManagerService(70): agentConnected pkg=com.android.providers.settings agent=android.app.backup.BackupAgent$BackupServiceBinder@40701198
11-05 16:30:38.445: V/LocalTransport(70): finishBackup()
11-05 16:31:17.939: D/SntpClient(70): request time failed: java.net.SocketException: Address family not supported by protocol
11-05 16:36:17.975: D/SntpClient(70): request time failed: java.net.SocketException: Address family not supported by protocol
11-05 16:41:18.036: D/SntpClient(70): request time failed: java.net.SocketException: Address family not supported by protocol
11-05 16:46:18.105: D/SntpClient(70): request time failed: java.net.SocketException: Address family not supported by protocol
11-05 16:47:00.296: D/dalvikvm(127): GC_CONCURRENT freed 353K, 53% free 2745K/5767K, external 2179K/2672K, paused 24ms+8ms
11-05 16:51:18.136: D/SntpClient(70): request time failed: java.net.SocketException: Address family not supported by protocol
11-05 16:56:18.147: D/SntpClient(70): request time failed: java.net.SocketException: Address family not supported by protocol
11-05 16:56:52.975: I/dalvikvm(70): Jit: resizing JitTable from 2048 to 4096
11-05 16:58:48.395: D/dalvikvm(70): GC_CONCURRENT freed 972K, 51% free 4474K/9095K, external 3125K/3903K, paused 34ms+16ms
11-05 17:01:18.197: D/SntpClient(70): request time failed: java.net.SocketException: Address family not supported by protocol
```

Comment: Where did you keep `NativeFormats-v2.so` file?

Comment: Simply put your shared library in `/libs/armeabi` directory in project File Hierarchy.

Comment: Thanks but,how to generate NativeFormats-v2.so

Comment: @user370305 what do you mean by "`/libs/armeabi`". My machine for example has only `/lib` and `/lib64`